# ListView error android

Tags: java, android, listview, logcat

I have a method that I use to recieve some information. I send to this method one string (the server direction), and two strings that contains the user and the password, and I recieve an String[] with all the information. Then I use the String[] values on to an ArrayAdapter, but I have the error that is showed on the logcat, I don't know why I have this error... In a preview version that I use my own values, without "String[] values" it works perfect, but now I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
String[] values;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_environment);   

    myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    user = myBundle.getString("user");
    password = myBundle.getString("password");

    values = request("http://myIp/XXX/post.php?request=1", user, password);  

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
}
```

The other method is the next:

```
    public String[] request(String requesturl, String user, String password)
{
    String result[] = new String[100]; 

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requesturl);

        String results = "";

        //Varibles POST
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));                        

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        response.getAllHeaders();
        response.getEntity();
        result[0] = "";                                                                         
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());           
            if(!results.equals("-1"))
            {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(results);

                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("edificios");

                int lengthJsonArr =jsonMainNode.length();
                for(int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);   
                    result[i] = jsonChildNode.optString("nombre"); 
                }
            }                 
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        result[0] = "error";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat of the error.

```
03-31 09:02:22.920: W/dalvikvm(2016): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b0ab90)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016): Process: com.example.en4dis, PID: 2016
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-31 09:02:22.950: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It cannot find a xml layout file. Probably the ones you use to create the adapter's views (see the constructor call) (android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1). Do you import android.R? Because you do refer to it. Keep in mind that android.R does not include your custom xml files (R.layout.activity_select_environment)

Comment: I try to do it one more time, write it and found R and all of that, it finds all correctly, but when I compile I have the same error. It could be important that when I used it with predeterminated values it works perfect but now it has this error?

Comment: if I use for example this: values = new String[] { "Edificio1", "Edificio2", "Edificio3" }; then the listview load correctly... what was wrong?

Comment: What is the difference between the value of the computed values variable and the predefind value? According to the docs it returns an optional String (empty or filled) http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29. Perhaps a check if the returned String is empty?

Comment: Actually it has to be "error" value on the String[] of request method, and then put it to the "values" string on the main code, but I don't know why it can't put it on the adapter and appears this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Issue is here:

```
String result[] = new String[100];
```

You initialise an Array with a Length of 100. Now you only fill part of your Array. This means in your memory you are going to have something like this

```
Index:       0       1            98     99
Values:   Value1 | Value2| ... | null | null
```

(EDIT: I know this is not completely accurate since there are only references stored but it is easier to understand like this)

Now when you pass this to your ArrayAdapter it will Parse each element and at the end it will try to layout a TextView with null as String. Apparently Android doesn't like that.

What you have to do is get an array with exactly the length of your values. I would suggest using a list first and creating an array later. For example (not tested pseudo code)

```
public String[] request(String requesturl, String user, String password){

   //init List
   List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(); 

   //add values to List like this
   values.add("myString");


   //return a array with the correct size at last
   return  values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);

}
```

Make sure to also do the same for your error case.